# Java code outside of the pipeline won't run on Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Looks like any code outside the pipe line won't be run on Dataflow. In the following example I get a `NullPointerException` for `TableSchema` in the `TableRowConverterFn.processElement` method. What is the right way to do this with Apache Beam/Dataflow?

```
     private static TableSchema TableSchema;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            TableSchema = TableSchemaReader.read(TableSchemaResource);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Table schema can not be read from {}. Process aborted.", TableSchemaResource);
            return;
        }

        DataflowDfpOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
                //.withValidation()
                .as(DataflowDfpOptions.class);

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        log.info("DFP data transfer from GS to BQ has started.");

        pipeline.apply("ReadFromStorage", TextIO.read()
                .from("gs://my-test/stream/*.gz")
                .withCompression(Compression.GZIP))
                .apply("TransformToTableRow", ParDo.of(new TableRowConverterFn()))
                .apply("WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                        .to(options.getTableId())
                        .withMethod(STREAMING_INSERTS)
                        .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_NEVER)
                        .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withSchema(TableSchema)); //todo: use withJsonScheme(String json) method instead


        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();

        log.info("DFP data transfer from GS to BQ is finished in {} seconds.", sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a TableRow from a CSV line
     */
    private static class TableRowConverterFn extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

            String[] split = c.element().split(",");

            //Ignore the header line
            //Since this is going to be run in parallel, we can't guarantee that the first line passed to this method will be the header
            if (split[0].equals("Time")) {
                log.info("Skipped header");
                return;
            }

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

                //This throws NEP!!!
                TableFieldSchema col = TableSchema.getFields().get(i);

                //String is the most common type, putting it in the first if clause for a little bit optimization.
                if (col.getType().equals("STRING")) {
                    row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
                } else if (col.getType().equals("INTEGER")) {
                    row.set(col.getName(), Long.valueOf(split[i]));
                } else if (col.getType().equals("BOOLEAN")) {
                    row.set(col.getName(), Boolean.valueOf(split[i]));
                } else if (col.getType().equals("FLOAT")) {
                    row.set(col.getName(), Float.valueOf(split[i]));
                } else {
                    //Simply try to write it as a String if
                    //todo: Consider other BQ data types.
                    row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
                }
            }
            c.output(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tip: add the `Java` tag to have your code auto-highlighted. As for the error you are getting, correct me if I'm wrong, but you never actually defined the variable `TableSchema` in the `TableRowConverterFn` function did you ?

Comment: @ThehBarTender great tip! Thanks. `TableSchema` is a static field. Sorry that I forgot to add it to the source code. I added that to the very top of the source code.

Comment: I can't find `TableSchemaReader` and `TableSchemaResource` anywhere in Beam, are those custom classes ?

Comment: @ThehBarTender yes. The schema is a file in resources. `TableSchemaReader` just reads it and creates a `TableSchema` object.

Answer (score 2):

Althought this code might work locally in a DirectRunner, it indeed can't work in a DataflowRunner. Here's why:

The DoFns created outside of your `main` function do **not** have access to your classes's (even static) variables with the DataflowRunner. This is, I believe (not 100% sure though), due to how Dataflow stages and serializes DoFns when running in the cloud.

Here's how you can overcome this issue:

```java
private static class TableRowConverterFn extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
    private static TableSchema tableSchema;

    public TableRowConverterFn(TableSchema tableSchema) {
        this.tableSchema = tableSchema;
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Then in your main function call

```
.apply("TransformToTableRow", ParDo.of(new TableRowConverterFn(tableSchema)));
```